# javascript does no excute when using a href to pass information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

In the index.php I use href to send value to another php file;

```
<a href="orderinfo.php?type=11" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">order</a>
```

and the orderinfo.php is like below.

```
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableOption()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body onload="disableOption()">
</body>

</html>
```

When I click the href in the main.php. it direct me to the orderinfo.php.
but the function disableOption() will not excute till I refresh the website by myself.
What's the problem here.

I don't know why . but is I don't add the type=11.It works fine.

```
<a href="orderinfo.php?" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">order</a>
```

try to clear the cache.and also add

```
<!-- no cache-->
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">  
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache, must-revalidate">  
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
```

still not work. I need to refresh the page manually, and the console will show the log info..
It's weird.should I put the whole web page here. because It's too big..

below is the whole webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
<!--prevent from become to big on desktop-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<!--import the JQuery JSlib-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Custom CSS-->
<style>     
#ad{
    text-align:center;
}
.pic{
    margin-left:0;
}
.price{

}
.discount{
    color:red;
}
.order{
    float:left;
    margin-left:40px;
}


.custom-corners .ui-bar {
    margin-top:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: inherit;
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}
.custom-corners .ui-body {
    border-top-width: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" class="page">

<div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>deal</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">option</a>

</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content" class="jqm-main">
    <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" class="jqm-tab">

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->

        <div id="one">

            <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <img class="pic" src="img/1.jpg">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><p class="price">100</p></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><p class="discount">80</p></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <a href="orderinfo.php?type=11" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">order</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <img class="pic" src="img/2.jpg">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><p class="price">100</p></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><p class="discount">80</p></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <a href="orderinfo.php?type=12" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">order</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
                    <h3>3</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <img class="pic" src="img/3.jpg">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><p class="price">100</p></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><p class="discount">80</p></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <a href="orderinfo.php?type=13" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">order</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div  id="two">


            <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">1</h3>
                <div class="ui-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan blandit fermentum. Pellentesque cursus mauris purus, auctor commodo mi ullamcorper nec. Donec semper mattis eros, nec condimentum ante sollicitudin quis. Etiam orci sem, porttitor ut tellus nec, blandit posuere urna. Proin a arcu non lacus pretium faucibus. Aliquam sed est porttitor, ullamcorper urna nec, vehicula lorem. Cras porttitor est lorem, non venenatis diam convallis congue.</p>
                </div>

            <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">2</h3>
                <div class="ui-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan blandit fermentum. Pellentesque cursus mauris purus, auctor commodo mi ullamcorper nec. Donec semper mattis eros, nec condimentum ante sollicitudin quis. Etiam orci sem, porttitor ut tellus nec, blandit posuere urna. Proin a arcu non lacus pretium faucibus. Aliquam sed est porttitor, ullamcorper urna nec, vehicula lorem. Cras porttitor est lorem, non venenatis diam convallis congue.</p>
                </div>

            <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">3</h3>
                <div class="ui-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan blandit fermentum. Pellentesque cursus mauris purus, auctor commodo mi ullamcorper nec. Donec semper mattis eros, nec condimentum ante sollicitudin quis. Etiam orci sem, porttitor ut tellus nec, blandit posuere urna. Proin a arcu non lacus pretium faucibus. Aliquam sed est porttitor, ullamcorper urna nec, vehicula lorem. Cras porttitor est lorem, non venenatis diam convallis congue.</p>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Powered by ATekNetwork</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the orderinfo.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>info</title>
<!--prevent from become to big on desktop-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<!--import the JQuery JSlib-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>


<!--Custom JavaScript-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    function disableOption()
    {

        //using flag to determin the selected options
        var flag;

        var objToday = new Date();

        //curHour = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? objToday.getHours() - 12 : (objToday.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getHours() : objToday.getHours());
        //get the time from the client device  NOTICE bug: if the time from the device is wrong may cause problem.
        curHour = objToday.getHours();

        if(curHour < 11){
            flag = 0;
            console.log("hello");
        }
        else if(curHour >= 11 && curHour < 12){
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if(curHour >= 12 && curHour < 13){
            flag = 2;
        }
        else{
            flag= 3;
        }


        console.log(curHour);
        var select = document.getElementById('select-choice-1');

        if(flag == 0){

            for (var i=0, option; option = select.options[i]; i++)
            {
                option.disabled = false;

            }

            //emulate(select);
        }

        if(flag == 1){

            for (var i=1, option; option = select.options[i]; i++)
            {
                option.disabled = false;

            }
            //emulate(select);

        }

        if(flag == 2){

            for (var i=2, option; option = select.options[i]; i++)
            {
                option.disabled = false;

            }
            //emulate(select);

        }

        if(flag == 3){

            for (var i=0, option; option = select.options[i]; i++)
            {
                option.disabled = true;

            }
            //emulate(select);

        }


    }
</script>
<!--Custom CSS-->
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body onload="disableOption()">

<div data-role="page" class="page">

<div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>info</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">option</a>

</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content" class="jqm-main">

<?php

    $type = $_GET['type']; 
    $info = "";

    if($type == 11){

        $info = "1";

    }

    if($type == 12){

        $info = "2";

    }

    if($type == 13){

        $info = "3";

    }

?>

<h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">info</h3>



<form action="sendmail.php" method="get">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="name">name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>


                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <div class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="textinput-disabled">type</label>
                        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="textinput-disabled" id="textinput-disabled" placeholder="Text input" value="<?php echo $info;?>">
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="phone">phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>


                    <li class="ui-field-contain">
                        <label for="address">adress</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-field-contain">

                        <label for="slider-2">num</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" data-mini="true" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="40" value="1" data-clear-btn="true">

                    </li>


                    <li class="ui-field-contain">

                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">time</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                                <option disabled="disabled" value="11-12">11-12</option>
                                <option disabled="disabled" value="12-1">12-1</option>
                                <option disabled="disabled" value="1-2">1-2</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>


                    </li>

                    <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">reset</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a" data-ajax="false">submit</div>
                        <fieldset>
                    </li>

                </ul>

</form><!--end form-->
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Powered by ATekNetwork</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Finaly I find the problem, the problem is that weird problem in JQuery mobile.
if you Put Your script code in the head element .It will not load into the dom till the web refresh.

So we can put the scripts into the tag below.

```
<div data-role="page" class="page">

<script>
//your javascirpt code goes here
</script>
</div>
```

and it works..

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: This may be a caching issue.

Comment: It should work fine. There is no problem in the code. Clear your cache as suggested by @Jeremy.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I put the whole page up.could you help check what's the probem here..

Comment: Use Firebug to make sure type=11 is actually being appended to the URL

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob It's appended to the URL.$_GET['type'] works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should load your script at the bottom of the page, it is a better practice, that way it loads after the page. Also, if you are using HTML5, you should no longer have to declare the script type.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- your content -->



    <script>
    function disableOption(){
        console.log("hello");
    }
    disableOption();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean I should put the script tag into the body tag? I mean, I think it should stay in the <head> tag.BTW,no need to use type.thanks for your attention

Comment: @robinclark007 yes, right before the closing </body> tag

Comment: I try your way, still not work at all. and the console didn't show the log info at all.

Comment: I suppose you already cleared your cache like the suggested above? I think we'd need additional info on your site's setup

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js** script tag from the main php and try again.

I too am facing [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301412/js-not-running-first-time-html-page-loads) and the only way the code works is when the above mentioned library is removed from the main page.

Comment: Thanks I find a better solution.we don't need to remove the jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js only thing we need to do is put the script into the div="page" element.That's ok.

Comment: @robinclark007 Can you please explain in detail about how you put the script in div="page" element ? Maybe it could help me in my issue too. Thanks.

Comment: Well, You can see the question.I add a solution at the bottom of the question,it seems jquery moible are using ajax to load information.so if you put the scripts into the <head></head> ,not work at all.another way to solve this is to put your script into the index files of your webpage.I havn't try this yet.